# Updating Git folder structure on push

Tags: git, git-push

I have a Git Repo folder structure as so:

```
.git
local.repo.only.files
web/
   --Files for remote production
```

I'm pushing this repo to a remote url, such as dest@git.myhost.com. However, the folder structure there is one file deeper. Essentially just:

`--Files on remote production`

Is there any way of pushing a specific folder's contents' to a remote?

Up until now, I've been create a nested git init inside the web folder, and pushing just that to the remote. Which has worked... but it's an inelegant solution.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. In general it's difficult to work with anything less than the entire repository in Git. Using Git as a release tool has severe limitations. A better release process will avoid a lot of hassle. To help, tell us what is the relationship between the `local.repo.only.files` and `web/`? Also, how are you pushing your files to the remote? That usually doesn't work, a remote is usually bare. Do you have hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been create a nested `git init` inside the web folder, and pushing just that to the remote. Which has worked... but it's an inelegant solution.

Either the web folder content is a generated one (one you can rebuild), in which case you don't need a nest git repo, and can deploy your files through rsynch/scp.

Or you do want a git repo on the remote side, in which case, that remote git repo should be a bare one, with a post-receive hook, which would copy the web subfolder content to your web http server folder.

Comment: Thank you! I'd never used scp or rsync before but it looks like I might be able to use it accomplish what I am looking for.